# How can I add one route to 2 different middleware (auth) without having to duplicate it in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, routes, middleware

I know this is a basic laravel question but don't know how do it. How can I add one route to 2 different middleware (auth) without having to duplicate it?

```
// =admin
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function() {
    Route::get('/dashboard', 'App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard');
    Route::get('make-a-sale', [PurchasesController::class, 'index'])->name('make-a-sale.index');
});
// =cashier
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'role:cashier']], function() {
    Route::get('/dashboard/cashier/profile', 'App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController@showCashierProfile')->name('dashboard.cashier.profile');
    Route::get('make-a-sale', [PurchasesController::class, 'index'])->name('make-a-sale.index');
});
```

I have this route and I don't want to repeat calling this per auth middleware: `Route::get('make-a-sale', [PurchasesController::class, 'index'])->name('make-a-sale.index');`

Comment: Only one of the routes will work here anyway. The other one will be overwritten. It's not clear to me what the problem actually is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have two routes with the same url.

```php
Route::get('make-a-sale', [PurchasesController::class, 'index'])->name('make-a-sale.index');
```

This route is inside both groups and since the url they will produce will be the same, only the second will remain.

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function() {
    Route::get('/dashboard', 'App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard');
    //Route::get('make-a-sale', [PurchasesController::class, 'index'])->name('make-a-sale.index');
// this route will be ignored because the other one has the same url
});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'role:cashier']], function() {
    Route::get('/dashboard/cashier/profile', 'App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController@showCashierProfile')->name('dashboard.cashier.profile');
    Route::get('make-a-sale', [PurchasesController::class, 'index'])->name('make-a-sale.index');
});
```

If you want Laravel to handle these two routes differently, you have to add a prefix:

```php
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'as' => 'admin.', 'middleware' => ['auth']], function() {
    Route::get('/dashboard', 'App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard');
    //Route::get('make-a-sale', [PurchasesController::class, 'index'])->name('make-a-sale.index');
// this route will be ignored because the other one has the same url
});

Route::group(['prefix' => 'cashier', 'as' => 'cashier.',  'middleware' => ['auth', 'role:cashier']], function() {
    Route::get('/dashboard/cashier/profile', 'App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController@showCashierProfile')->name('dashboard.cashier.profile');
    Route::get('make-a-sale', [PurchasesController::class, 'index'])->name('make-a-sale.index');
});
```

This way, when the url will be prefixed with `admin`, the first route will be called (without the `role:cashier` middleware).

Notice that I added a route name prefix (`'as' => 'admin.'` / `'as' => 'cashier.'`) so you can call each one by name, using:

```php
route('admin.make-a-sale.index'); // admin/make-a-sale
//or
route('cashier.make-a-sale.index'); // cashier/make-a-sale
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add, if someone wants to fix the Laravel blade error below whenever you clear your browser cache and was automatically logout:

```
*Attempt to read property "name" ...*
```

You need to add all your routes inside the:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () { 
    // routes here
});
```

This will redirect you to login once that happens.